# Problems with Laravel Controller class

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I know this question has already been asked a few times but none of the answers has worked for me, that's why I'm asking it again.

I'm trying to make a little website in Laravel and I created a route and a controller but when I try to access it in the url, I get this error:

```
Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException
Target class [Admin\PlanController] does not exist.
```

Here is my `web.php`:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;


Route::get('admin/plans', 'Admin\PlanController@index')->name('plans.index');

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Here is my `PlanController.php`

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PlanController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
        return view('admin.pages.plans.index');
    }
}
```

And if it helps in any way, here is my `RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
    protected $namespace = 'App\\Http\\Controllers';

    public function boot()
    {
        $this->configureRateLimiting();

        $this->routes(function () {
            Route::prefix('api')
                ->middleware('api')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/api.php'));

            Route::middleware('web')
                ->namespace($this->namespace)
                ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
        });
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the default namespace I think. can you add your routes ? Laravel 8?

Comment: make sure u r accessing  in your `anchor` tag with correct `name`  `plans.index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems to be fine with your code. Confirm with a directory of the controller must be

```
app\Http\Controllers\Admin
```

Or make changings

```
$this->routes(function () {
        Route::middleware('web')
            ->namespace('App\Http\Controllers')
            ->group(base_path('routes/web.php'));
```

without using getting namespace value here as a variable in `RouteServiceProvider.php`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Laravel 8, it's best to use the new route syntax like so:

```
use App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PlanController;

Route::get('/admin/plans', [PlanController::class, 'index'])->name('plans.index');
```

Make sure the controller is in the correct directory `app/Http/Controllers/Admin`

Comment: thanks for you comment but it did not work :/ same error

Comment: Did you clear the route cache ? `php artisan route:cache`

Comment: yes, using both ```route:cache``` and ```route:clear```. I also ran the command ```composer dump autoload```

Answer (score 0):

You can describe the full namespace in your route;

```
Route::get('admin/plans','App\Http\Controllers\Admin\PlanController@index')->name('plans.index');
```